# python3 - problem with parsing json after response data using (unirest)

Tags: json, python-3.x, fastapi

I'm making `HTTPSConnection` using `(Python)Unirest` and the response have charecters like `"` , `\` and `\n` so I hard-coded my python code and finally i got the right response without any characters on console using `sys.stderr.write(data2)`

```
    @router.get("/data", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    async def data_detail(type: str ):
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("example.com")
            conn.request("GET", "/test.php?type="+type)
            res = conn.getresponse()
            data = res.read()
            data2 = data.decode("utf-8")
            data2 = data2[1:-1]
            data2 = data2.replace("\\n", '')
            data2 = data2.replace("\\", '')

            res = {
                "status"    :   "OK" ,
                "result"    :   data2
                }
            return JSONResponse(res)
        except Exception as e:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Error")
```

now when i return `data` to user the backslash `\` back again to the the data response

the data i received from third party is :

```
"{\"list1\":[{\"one\":\"one\",\"tow\":\"tow\",\"three\":\"three\"},{\"test1\":\"test1\",\"test2\":\"test2\",\"test3\":\"test3\"},],\"list2\":[]}\n"
```

after replacing characters i got this on system console

```
{"list1":[{"one":"one","tow":"tow","three":"three"},{"test1":"test1","test2":"test2","test3":"test3"}],"list2":[]}
```

but when i add this data to final json response the backslashes back again to the output and all the data stored as one value in `result`

**any solution for this problem**

Comment: You never decode the json you receive - if you expect JSON back, decode it to a proper Python structure, then include that structure instead of the raw JSON - unless you want the JSON wrapped inside a string, in which case escaping `"` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I  provided a simple JSON as example .check it please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode the JSON.

First `import json` and then try replacing:

```
data2 = data2[1:-1]
data2 = data2.replace("\\n", '')
data2 = data2.replace("\\", '')
```

by

```
data2 = json.loads(data2)
```

After this, you final json response will be constructed correctly.

You should use `json.dumps(data2)` to print this data to console. In general, use `json.dumps` to pretty print python data as JSON.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html for more help in handling JSON in python.

Answer (score 0):

You are never replacing a single backslash. Do you need to add a line like

```
data2 = data2.replace("\", '')
```

Comment: I already replaced it by adding this line `data2 = data2.replace("\\", '')` the output of `data2` is right on the console but the backslashes backs again when I return the response to the user